# How to run application with parameters from within java application on mac osx

Tags: java, macos

I am writing a small java application to load ZDoom with custom wad files on mac osx and am having trouble executing the command.

I have generated a string within the application that will run ZDoom and load the custom wad, I have tested this by copy-pasting the string from the netbeans breakline debugger and running it directly in terminal.

When I run the code through my application ZDoom does load up but it does so without the custom wad so I believe it is executing without it's arguments.

I have tried two different techniques to run the command:

```
private void loadZdoom()  {
    // get selected wad
    String wad = (String) wadListComboBox.getSelectedItem();

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(defaultZdoomInstallPath + "/Contents/MacOS/zdoom", "-file", defaultZdoomWadsPath.replace(" ", "\\ ") + "/" + wad);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    try {
        Process p = builder.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
}
```

And

```
private void loadZdoom()  {
    // get selected wad
    String wad = (String) wadListComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    String runCommand = defaultZdoomInstallPath + "/Contents/MacOS/zdoom " + "-file " + defaultZdoomWadsPath.replace(" ", "\\ ") + "/" + wad;

    try {
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runTime.exec(runCommand);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are the resources in a location that ZDoom can find?

Comment: ZDoom loads whatever wad file you pass in, the command generated by this app is: /Applications/ZDoom.app/Contents/MacOS/zdoom -file /Users/colinmctaggart/Library/Application\ Support/ZDoom/Bonus.wad which works as expected when pasted into terminal so yeah, Zdoom can defiantly access the wad files.

Comment: (Why use Java for this task?)

Comment: Because I'm a php developer and don't know any other languages that can run as a desktop app.  I learned java in uni so that's why I'm using it.  What language would you have used?  I may have a go at converting it when I have more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was, I was escaping the space in the path to the wad file as you need to do this in terminal but it seems this is unnecessary in JAVA.  All is working as expected now :)